# How do I send data from input to two different apis in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a register page. I want the user to be able to agree to sign up to a newsletter by checking off a box. I have written this code to handle the submit:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const errMsg = valid(name, email, password, cf_password)
    if(errMsg){
      return dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {error: errMsg}})
    }

    dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {loading: true}})

    if(checked === 'on'){
      const res = await postData('subscribe', userData)
      if(res.err){
        return dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {error: res.err}})
      }
      return dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {success: res.msg}})
    }

    const res = await postData('auth/register', userData)

    if(res.err){
      return dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {error: res.err}})
    }
    
    return dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {success: res.msg}})
  }
```

When the user submits now he is only subscribing to the newsletter and not also registering, because a response has already been sent. Is there a way to send two responses to different api endpoints in the same submit function?

Comment: Why not simply remove the `return` statements when you dispatch the subscribe events? That way your code can continue to the register logic.

Comment: @juliomalves This was the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: remove the returns in the if checked statement.

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const errMsg = valid(name, email, password, cf_password)
    if(errMsg){
      return dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {error: errMsg}})
    }

    dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {loading: true}})

    if(checked === 'on'){
      const res = await postData('subscribe', userData)
      if(res.err){
        dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {error: res.err}}) // removed return here
      }
      dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {success: res.msg}}) // and here
    }

    const res = await postData('auth/register', userData)

    if(res.err){
      return dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {error: res.err}})
    }
    
    return dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {success: res.msg}})
  }
```